# How to use omit for Test::Unit::TestCase in Ruby to omit/skip the execution of a certain method/test

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testunit

I am trying to skip/omit some tests. My environment is Ruby/selenium webdriver/Test Unit.

This how the structure looks:

```
class HeadTestCase < Test::Unit::TestCase
class UnitTest1 < CCTestCase

class UnitTest1 < CCTestCase
  def web_test_01
    omit("Skipping this test")
    some code related to test
  end
```

Omit method signature is `omit("Message",&block)`

I dont know what I should put for `&block`.

Also is this a correct way to skip a test?

Answer (score 0):

Using `omit` the way you are using it here looks correct. The trick is that you need to be using the [test-unit gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/test-unit) and not the minimal version of Test::Unit included with the Ruby distribution.

```
gem install test-unit
```

You do not need to use a code block with `omit` unless you want only part of the code in your test case to be omitted. Use `do` and `end` as usual for a block:

```
def web_test_01
  omit("Skipping part of the test") do
    # Code here would be skipped
  end
  # Code here would be executed
end
```